# In Unix, how can I capture output in the terminal and dump it into a file that's not been created?

Tags: shell, unix

I have a python script that runs at times and when it does it can creates error messages in the terminal. How can I capture these errors and dump it into a new file?

Thanks for help!

Comment: More details please as we wouldn't know how you want your new file created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
myscript.sh 2> errlog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a concept:

```
TS=$(date +%s)  # Gets timestamp.
script.py 2> "errors.$TS.log"
```

Comment: Awesome as well! Love the idea of having a timestamp on a file!